# How to create Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>;

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Is it possible to create `Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>()` which can be used in different htmlHelpers (for instance in `CheckBoxFor()`), if I have a model object

```
this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper
```

and name of the property (through reflection).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure:

```
static Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>> CreateExpression<TModel,TProperty>(
    string propertyName)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "x");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProperty>>(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName), param);
}
```

then:

```
var lambda = CreateExpression<SomeModel, bool>("IsAlive");
```

Comment: No! Marc Gravell shouldn't be here! This is a question for Jon Skeet!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Simple and effective!

Comment: I have another connected question - what if I have in my View a more complicated property, an instance of a class. So not just a simple property which is String or Boolean, but an object which inside itself has more properties. For example, this is how I declare simple checkbox for such "inside" attributes '@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Config.All)'. Is it possible to created such lambda, which would reflect the property inside an object -  "m => m.Config.All".

Comment: @Anelook you mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208214/construct-lambdaexpression-for-nested-property-from-string/16208620#16208620

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, very close! But can I somehow convert it to Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>? I successfully can get correct lambda, but cannot cast it to the type I need.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: @Anelook, you should post your solution.

Comment: Is there any type of issue using "x" if this methods was used multiple times to create an expression tree to execute?  (IE multiple "x"s in the expression tree)

Comment: @ErikPhilips parameter expressions don't even need to be named; I suspect it only uses the name for the `.ToString()` representation of the expression tree. Obviously if you use the same name for multiple expressions: expect the `ToString()` to be slightly confusing.