# How to create Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> without TProperty type explicit

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

The answer of [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217410/how-to-create-expressionfunctmodel-tproperty) explains how to create expressions just like that:

```
var lambda = CreateExpression<SomeModel, bool>("IsAlive");
```

It's possible avoid the explicit type bool and that the method obtains the return type from "IsAlive" property?

Something like this:

```
var lambda = CreateExpression<SomeModel>("IsAlive");
```

And lambda will be a `Expression<Func<SomeModel, bool>>`.

And in:

```
var lambda = CreateExpression<SomeModel>("StringProperty");
```

lambda will be a `Expression<Func<SomeModel, string>>`.

Comment: do you want to avoid explicit type for some reason ? If it is because you want to reuse that for different models which do not share any interface type, you might want to use dynamic maybe. But I am not quite sure if it would work

Comment: I already try with dynamic but don't works.

Comment: The type is really needed here, otherwise how would you expect to use the returned expression?

Comment: @DavidG That is exactly the problem you run into.  Not sure it's a good approach but it was a fun learning exercise.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi The point is that it's almost certainly not a good approach. You've already found out that you now have an expression that is weakly types (i.e. a `LamdaExpression` instead of `Expression<Func<SomeModel, string>`).

Comment: @DavidG Agreed, that's what the answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** in fact do this, but the type becomes unknown.  The object returned from this method will be of the proper type `Expression<Func<Test, string>>` but **cannot be strong typed at compile time**:

```
    static LambdaExpression CreateExpression<TModel>(string propertyName)
    {
        var t = typeof(TModel);
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "x");
        //get the type for the 2nd generic arg
        var propType = t.GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
        //make the generic type Func<TModel, TProp>
        Type genericFuncType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(TModel), propType });
        //get the Expression.Lambda method
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Expression).GetMethods().First(a => a.Name == "Lambda" && a.GetParameters().Length == 2);
        //get the Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProp>> method
        MethodInfo mi2 = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { genericFuncType });
        //Call Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProp>>
        return (LambdaExpression)mi2.Invoke(null, new object[] { Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName), new ParameterExpression[] { param }});
    }
```

**However note that the return type is now somewhat unknown and will need cast to use (or use dynamic).**

So now you need even more code to cast it.  Perhaps this would be useful in some sort of factory or such - not sure your use case.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var theExpression = CreateExpression<Test>("Name");
        var theExpressionStrongType = theExpression as Expression<Func<Test, string>>;
        //now you could use theExpressionStrongType

        //or do this and go wild. :)
        dynamic d = theExpression;


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Disclaimer: if you seriously want to use this in a production environment, I would clean up the code a LOT to just get refection types once, etc, etc...

Comment: Thanks! You really are a jedi.